# Unity - Read specific part from a txt file

Tags: c#

I'm making a small game to practice c#. In this game there's going to be NPCs that will say some random sentences fitting for the situation. What I want to do is store these sentences in a separate txt file located in the same location as the executable and not packed in it so I can edit these lines without needing to rebuild the entire game every time.

What I'm having trouble is I want to have multiple different types of lines/dialogue stored in this one txt file.

For example, in this file there could be the heading [GREETINGS] under which there would be the list of dialogue options. Under the greetings there could then be another heading [COMBAT], and again a list of lines underneath it.

The game would then load up the file, and when it needs to it would move to the correct heading and then randomly pick one of the dialogue options under that heading. So I would like to know if it's possible to read txt files like this and to get a string containing only that one line of dialogue to write on the speech bubbles. Alternatively the game could read the txt file to create multiple lists of strings, each list containing each line of dialogue from one heading and each string being one line.

Also, related to this subject, is it possible to write variables into this kind of text and then have the program check for variables in the string? For example, if playerName was John, and the line saved in the txt file read "Oh hello playername!" the game would then output "Oh hello John!" I was thinking this could possibly be done by using special words in the lines, like in the before mentioned example one could use [playername] and the program would then replace any [playername] in the strings to playerName the variable.

Comment: You'd have a way easier time if you stored your data in an existing format like JSON or XML. Otherwise you'll have to write your own parsing logic to find and extract this data. Though without showing what you tried and where you are struggling this question is off-topic for SO

Comment: What you've described is possible. However, it's gonna be easier to read & write json. Json.Net would be a good library to look at https://www.nuget.org/packages/Newtonsoft.Json/